# Присвоить переменной содержимое контента с выборочного URL

Tags: javascript

Подскажите, как в javascript переменной присвоить значение всего содержимого по url?

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function startAjax(url){
      var request;
      if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
          request = new XMLHttpRequest();
      } else if(window.ActiveXObject){
          request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");  
      } else {
          return;
      }

      request.onreadystatechange = function(){
            switch (request.readyState) {
               case 4:{
               if(request.status==200){
                            var foo = request.responseText;    
                            alert ( foo );
                         }
                          else alert("Ошибка: сервер вернул статус: "+ request.status);
                break
                }
            }      
        }
        request.open ('GET', url, true);
        request.send ('');
      }

      window.onload = startAjax('url');
</script>
```

В строке `window.onload = startAjax('url');`, url - заменить на адрес

Comment: на другом домене работать не будет нельзя так сделать скажем с адресом http://vk.com

Comment: функция $.ajax из пакета jquery поддерживает кроссдоменные запросы: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ свойство crossDomain

Comment: кроссдоменные запросы не работают, если отсутствует cors, покажите мне  запрос $.ajax() к vk.com

Comment: Тогда таким запросом напрячь свой веб-сервер. Пусть возьмёт страничку и отдаст просящему.

Comment: @eicto Почему не будет? У меня работало, посмотрите сами. Только к vk.com я не пробовал.

Answer (score 0):

```
var foo = window.location.href;
```

Comment: не подходит

Answer (score -1):

```
var foo = window.location
```

foo будет равным URL

Comment: Не совсем поняли вопрос. Мне нужно переменной присвоить контент страницы по определенному адресу.

Comment: @Saturn в том-же домене ?

Comment: Нет. Я видимо неправильно сформулировал вопрос. Значение переменной должно быть получено из контента страницы по определенному адресу

Comment: невозможно, кроме случаев, когда определенный адрес так-же контролируется вами ( cors )

Comment: @eicto Вы серьезно?

Comment: совершенно, гуглите same origin policy